# Variable scope : not seen within callback function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Basically, I have several friends that I want to:
  - see on a map
  - list in a table

I have a loop on the friends list, for each iteration I:
  - create a google maps marker
  - add friend in a list

**FIRST PROBLEM**: For the marker I add an event listener to be able to display an infowindow. I use the title of the marker to be able to retrieve info on the friend... that's only a silly wokaround because "id" is not known within the ajax method retrieving the friend. This is my first problem. I'd like to be able to use title for a real title (not an id) and manage to get the id within the ajax callback in another way.

**SECOND PROBLEM** For the list, I add a "li" entry for each friend and add an event listener on the li.a link to be able to display the friend details. "id" is not seen neither.

Those 2 problems are of the same familly.

Below is the code I've done. Obviously something wrong but cannot figure out what I need to change to access id within the callback functions.

note: I use jquery mobile for a HTML5 application.

```
for(j=0;j<friends.length;j++){
      var lat = friends[j][1];
      var long = friends[j][2];
      var id = friends[j][3];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng,
                               map: map,
                               title: id
                              });

      // Add friends to list
      $("#friend_list ul").append('<li><a id="details' + id + '" rel="external" data-transition="slide">' + id + '</a></li>');

      // Add event handler when details:id is clicked
      $('#details' + id).click(function(){
        alert(id + ' clicked');   // DOES NOT WORK AS ID IS NOT KNOWN IN THIS METHOD
      });

      // Add listener on click action for marker created above
      // I PASS THE TITLE OF SELF AS ID IS NOT KNOWN IN THIS METHOD
      // IF I use: url: "/friend/" + id => ONLY THE LAST VALUE OF THE ID IS TAKEN INTO ACCOUNT 
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        self = this;
        $.ajax({
          url: "/friend/" + self.title,  
          success: function(details){
            var message = details["lastname"] + ' ' + details["firstname"];
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
              { content: message,
                size: new google.maps.Size(50,50)
              }
            );
            infowindow.open(map,self);
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

Any idea of what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here is how the ids can be picked off of the list items when clicked:
//...your..loop
var id = friends[j][3];

$('#friendlist').append('<li><a href="#" id="details'+ id +'">Friend</a></li>')
$('#details'+id).click(function() { alert(this.id.replace('details',''))})

//and for the gmarker:
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
var gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng,title: 'desired title here' });

//then create a secondary id for the marker -- sort of hash?
//simple case - each marker has unique latlng, so just concat them n do:
//based on Marino Šimić's trick
document[''+lat+''+long] = id

GEvent.addListener(gmarker, "click", function(marker, latlng) {
    alert('marker id:'+document[''+latlng.lat()+''+latlng.lng()] ) //your desired id here
});

//and then add the marker to the map
map.addOverlay(gmarker);
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the list stuff. Regarding the marker stuff, I added you in the comment I made above as this is not what I need as I'd like to use the title for something else than an id.

Comment: why don't use the id as parameters in this case ? I have the error GEvent is not defined.

Comment: ensure that the google maps api script is properly referenced, i.e the `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=abcdefg&sensor=true_or_false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>` is there. In my case, I was inferring the use of API V.2

Answer (score 1):

I did not read you whole problem because I need to hurry up but

the document object is always visible in scope

if you use

```
 document["something"] = id;
```

you will be able to get the

```
var something = document["something"];
```

from anywhere

not that it is a good design decision to have everything in the document object but to let you know ;)

Comment: @marino-simic this does not work either, only the last value of document["current_id"] is taken into account

Answer (score 0):

Is marker not the variable for the google maps marker?

So you should be able to access marker.title to get the id.

Comment: @mcnemesis I do access marker.title to get the id because I set "title: id" in the marker options. The things is I'd like to use the marker's title for something else than an id (a name for instance). Set the id in the title is the only way I found to be able to get the id back later on but this is not what I'll need.

Comment: ahh I get it. You might want to edit your question to make that more clear.